# Could the Universe be Toroidal with a Black Hole at the Centre?

Tags: universe

Thought experiment that occurred to me. Rather than a Big Bang, the Universe Cycles through a black hole at the centre. It looks like a big bang upon exit when it goes through an expansion phase, cycles around and then collapses back in the other side. So it is a continuous cycle. Would this explain the recent James Web findings of fully formed Galaxies a few hundred million years after the "big bang"? Does it go some way to explain dark matter?

Comment: How do you think the universe "cycles" through this mysterious black hole, the existence of which would be an even bigger mystery than a "simple" Big Bang ?

Comment: Also, where does "toroidal" enter the scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There are several such [cyclic models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_model) in cosmology. One of the best known is Roger Penrose's [conformal cyclic cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_cyclic_cosmology) model. All of these models are currently theoretical - although various experimental tests of these models have been proposed, none have been definitively passed. Indeed, current observational data supports a model of [accelerating expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerating_expansion_of_the_universe), in which the ultimate fate of the universe is a [heat death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe) or "Big Freeze".

Since the beginning of each cycle in cyclic models is a hot, structureless big bang, they do not help to solve the problem of early galaxy formation. I'm not clear how you think they might help to explain dark matter.